# Flash.ocx Windows 7 64bit WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, flash, windows64

i'm developing wpf application for load swf files, i'm using AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll and Interop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll. In win 32bit the aplication run but in 64bit a message error is shown "This application needs Flash.ocx file, which is not contained in this version of Windows.". I tryed copy this file contained in Windows Xp, but not resolve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flash is not 64-bit on Windows, and you cannot load 32-bit flash into a 64-bit process. You need to compile your project architecture to always run 32-bit.

In your Project's properties, go to the "Build" tab and change "Platform Target" to "x86". You'll have to do this for all configurations, such as Debug and Release.

Comment: Tnks man, i change for x86, but did not "Rebuild Solution", only Build (F6). Now run perfecly. Tnks